# small info dialogue on " i " or " ? " click on android

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

How to open a small info dialogue on android when clicking info or question mark button , similar to the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot with open dialogue on ? Click]

Comment: That's not a dialog. It's just a view. Are you just asking what that's called? It's a PopupWindow. In Compose, it's a Popup.